# How do you change the app icon color depending on in-app user preferences?

Tags: ios, swift

#### In app color themes

> Red      Yellow      Green      Blue

#### Users

> User A      User B      User C      User D      User E

#### In app user preferences

> User A (Red)      User B (Blue)     User C (Yellow)      User D (Green)     User E (Red)

Is it possible to make it so that the app icon itself has that specific color for each user based on their in app preferences?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the app icon with this function:

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("iconName", completionHandler: { error in /* Handle error */ }
```

For your case, you should have 4 icons (one per color theme).

But first, you must define all of your icons in the `info.plist`

[**This tutorial**](https://medium.com/swiftworld/swift-world-change-your-apps-icon-programmatically-in-ios-10-3-8e706a3206b3) will help you